# How to grab string from a HTML document using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to grab a string from a HTML page.  This string lives inside a div tag with no ID, and has an ever changing title property.

it looks something like this:

```
<div title = [this title changes depending on how the page is pulled up]>
EmailAddress abc@xyz
</div>
```

I want to be able to grab "**abc@xyz**" out of this whole mess.

This HTML document is ever changing, the only thing I know for sure that stays the same is that the string I want to grab will always be preceded by "**EmailAddress**"

I've been staring at this for 3 hours with no progress.  I'd be very thankful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: have you tried using [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Comment: What evil stuff do you want to do with those e-mails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );

for ( var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++ ) {
    if ( divElements[i].innerText.match( 'EmailAddress' ) ) {
        // your div 
        var mail_id =  divElements[i].innerText.replace('EmailAddress ','');
    }
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTbcw/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any way of narrowing down the containing element via an ID, then you can try reading in the body HTML and using regex to retrieve the text:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
var result = html.match(/EmailAddress\s([^<]+)</i)[1];
```

This is a very rudimentary regular expression, but should do the job to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('div[title]'), email;
if(x.length){
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        var inner = x[i].textContent || x[i].innerText;
        if(/EmailAddress/.test(inner)){
            email = inner.substring(inner.indexOf('EmailAddress') + 13);
            email = email.replace(/\s.*$/, '')
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T9rhA/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var divText=$(this).text();
    var ok=divText.contains('EmailAddress')
    if(ok){
      alert(divText);
    }
});
```